# inserting data with bulk insert output null

Tags: sql

I don't have any error when I ran the stored procedure of bulk insert but when I ran

`EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp journalDAB.dbo.FileData out  c:\test.txt -S SABRINE-PC\TEST -c -T'`

I had this output an empty table.

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp journalDAB.dbo.FileData out  c:\test.txt -S SABRINE-PC\TEST -c -T'
```

[image: Output data]

Comment: What is the source of the data you're inserting? Can you check that you can access it? Do you have a sample row from it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]